# Why does my laptop resume immediately after suspend in ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: suspend, lenovo, 19.04

I seem to be having some problem with suspend mode. Every time I try to suspend my laptop, it just locks the screen. Or maybe it successfully suspends just to resume only an instant after. What could cause such a behaviour?

I'm running 64-bit Ubuntu 19.04 on a Lenovo ideapad 310-15ISK laptop.

Comment: I have not connected any usb device